# Is it possible to change the background of a sub screen (PreferenceScreen) of a PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, background, preferenceactivity

I found that you can change the background of a `PreferenceActivity` by using `getListView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);`

However, if you go to any deeper PreferenceScreens the background returns to being black.

There don't appear to be any methods in `PreferenceScreen` that would allow changes to the background either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nested PreferenceScreens are supposed to take the theme from the parent however due to this bug http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4611&q=preference%20nested&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars they don't and I don't know of how to set the background manually in the nested preference. Hopefully this helps at least explain why.

Would love to hear if you find a workaround :)

Comment: So far I'm just thinking to have it launch another PreferenceActivity.  Seems silly, but that's all I can think of so far.  Thanks for the info.